# javascript template html

Tags: javascript, html, json, templates

I am templating **HTML** through javascript with this function :

```
 parseTemplate = function(tmpl, data) {
   var regexp;

  for (k in data) {
     regexp = new RegExp('{' + k + '}', 'g');
     tmpl = tmpl.replace(regexp, data[k]);
    }
   return tmpl;
   }
```

with a `JSON` object like

```
JSONdata = { 
  prop1 : val,
  prop2 : val,
  prop3 : {
           prop1of3 : 
           prop2of3 :
           ...
           }
  ... 
  }
```

Using curly braces in `HTML` and the righe `template` , I'm able to render all elements like `prop1` or `prop2` . Otherwise I'm unable to render ,e.g. , `prop1of3` , because the function is unable to find (?) it. Can you suggest a solution to render also the property of elements in this kind of JSON object? 
jQuery is appreciate

Answer (score 0):

...you're working with a string that you've pulled out of a RegEx.

Because you're working with a string, `data["prop1.sub_prop2"]` is not going to work, if you're actually trying to get `data.prop1.sub_prop2`.

So either you need to make your object shallow:

```
data = {
    prop1 : "",
    a_obj_prop_1 : "",
    a_obj_prop_2 : ""
};
```

...which isn't going to make life much easier...

...or you need to take the string that you got from the RegEx, and check it for `.`, and if they're there, split the string into an array, and then loop through that array, grabbing the next object down...

```
var parts_arr = "obj_a.client.id".split("."),
    key,
    item = data;

while (parts_arr.length > 0) {
    key = parts_arr.shift();
    item = item[key];
}
```

When you're done, `item` should be equal to whatever is behind the last `.`.

Of course, if there are no `.` in the template, then you want to skip over this, entirely.
You could also write it recursively.

There are all kinds of ways to get this working.

Hopefully, this one is pretty clear.

Comment: Yes it is really pretty clear. I'm wondering if all this manipulation worth it. I guess that something like mustache.js could make my life easier. I'm really in doubt.

Comment: That all comes down to how much more you need to do.  What I mean is using something that small will allow you to write your templates like: `<h1>{ article.title }</h1>` and `data.article.title` will hold the stuff that you're looking for. If you need to start adding logic (if|for|while|etc), then your system will need an overhaul, or you'll need to use a library.  But seriously, turning that 2-line while loop into a function called `getData` or however you'd want to do it is a really compact way of allowing the kind of templating you currently need. If your needs change/grow, learn a library.

Comment: It doesn't need to be very complex. The sample in my answer is simpel and powerfull. For loops etc one could create a helper function to assist templating.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a nice example that I personally use.

http://jsfiddle.net/g9e6u/

The trick is to match the insides of the braches with a regex and then use a closure to decide what to replace the match with. In this case the `_renderProperty()` decides what the value should be. The function takes the context `ctx` and appends the matched string `name` to it. So matching `hobbies.beach` will be evaluated as `ctx.hobbies.beach`. The `eval` does the evaluation and assigns the final value to the variable named `value`.
As a bonus you can use javascript inside the braces as well.

```
function Template(html) {
    this.html = html;

    this.render = function (context) {
        var self = this;
        return this.html.replace(/\{(.+?)\}/g, function (full, group) {
            return self._renderProperty(group, context);
        });
    }

    this._renderProperty = function (name, ctx) {
        var value;
        eval('value = ctx.' + name);
        return value;
    }
};

var context = {
    name:'John Doe',
    age: 200,
    hobbies: {
        beach:'I like walking there',
        flute:'Sounds like an angel',
        deep: {
            sea:'deep sea diving'
        }
    }
};

var t = new Template("My name is {name.replace(/o/, 'X')}, {age} years old. One of my hobbies is the beach because {hobbies.beach}. I also like {hobbies.deep.sea.toUpperCase()}");

var output = t.render(context);
alert(output);
```